# How to make jdbc PAYARA connection to CloudSQL from GKE

Tags: kubernetes, jdbc, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have a project into PAYARA server full with JDBC Connectiones. The project works fine over VMs (actually GCP).

But I need migrate to GKE. I have a payara server full running on GCP POD but i don't know make a JDBC Connection to CLoudSQL.

Please helpme.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Cloud SQL connector for Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory).

You might also be interested in the Cloud SQL Auth proxy, which is covered in the ["Connecting from Google Kubernetes Engine"](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine).